# Show textblock when selecting radiobutton with jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, onchange

I have a small challenge with jQuery and two radiobuttons. I like to show a textblock when selecting on radiobutton and hide the same textblock when selecting the other radiobutton. The initial state is to show no textblock.

I have the following HTML code:

```
<span class="radiogroupline"><input type="radio" name="feedback" id="Ja" value="Ja">
<label for="Ja">Ja</label></span>
<span class="radiogroupline"><input type="radio" name="feedback" id="Nee"   class="feedback" value="Nee">
<label for="Nee">Nee</label></span>
<div class="text-feedback hidden">Dynamisch textblok</div>
```

And I have wrote the following jQuery:

```
$('input[name="feedback"]').on("change", function() {
    $('.text-feedback').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

The challenge now is to accomplish how to show only the textblock when selecting the second radiobutton and hide when selecting the first radiobutton... Hope somebody can helps me?

Cheers,
Kessi

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('input[name="feedback"]').on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Nee') {
        $('.text-feedback').removeClass('hidden');
    }
    else {
        $('.text-feedback').addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/nKYw9/1/)

Comment: That wouldn't switch back to visible if the radio button changed again though.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have single event handler for two element, you need to identify them and put condition to show on one element click and hide on other element click.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CtYR5/)**

```
$('input[name="feedback"]').on("change", function(event) {
    if(event.target.id == 'Ja')      
    $('.text-feedback').removeClass('hidden');
    else
    $('.text-feedback').addClass('hidden');

});
```

Comment: Thanks Adil. I am a newbie with jQuery. This works like a charme... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name="feedback"]').on("change", function() {
  if $('input[name="feedback"]').val()=='Ja'
  {
    $('.text-feedback').css('display','block');
  } else {
    $('.text-feedback').css('display','none');
  }
});
```

For the record the other answers make sense in context if the class hidden does something other than set display to none and isn't only used in this kind of instance. If it doesn't lose it from the CSS and just control the display as I've laid out.

Answer (score 1):

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/223PN/1/

```
<span class="radiogroupline"><input type="radio" name="feedback"   id="Ja" value="Ja" >
<label for="Ja" >Ja</label></span>
<span class="radiogroupline"><input type="radio" name="feedback" id="Nee"   class="feedback" value="Nee" checked>
<label for="Nee">Nee</label></span>
<div class="text-feedback hidden">Dynamisch textblok</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('input[name="feedback"]').on("change", function() {
  $('.text-feedback').fadeToggle();
});
```